# How do I compare lists in python?

Tags: python

So I am currently working on some sort of mastermind problem and the program wants me to compare lists, I kind of got it but it keeps giving me an error: "argument of type 'int' is not iterable on line 12"

this is what I have so far:

```
import random

# These lists will be used as tests in your check_values function
computer_list = [1,2,3,5]
user_list = [2,7,3,4]
lst = []

def check_values(computer_list, user_list):
    for i in range(4):
        if user_list[i] in computer_list and user_list[i] in computer_list[i]:
            lst.extend("RED")
            return lst
        i = i + 1

check_values(computer_list, user_list)
```

how do I make it

A. stop throwing me an error despite it being a list not an int

B. compare the lists and have it print based on certain conditions, the 3 colors being RED, BLACK, and WHITE, white for the number in user_list that is in computer_list but in the wrong spot, red bring for if the number in user_list that is in computer_list and the right spot, and finally black when the number in user_list that is not in computer_list

C. actually print what I want it to print and not print the thing despite the conditions of the if statement not being met

?

Comment: Despite what "being a list not an int"?

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the TypeError by simply changing:

`user_list[i] in computer_list[i]` to `user_list[i] == computer_list[i]`

Reason being is because `user_list[i]` and  `computer_list[i]` are both values not lists.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer all your questions, but...

```
if user_list[i] in computer_list and user_list[i] in computer_list[i]:
```

When you use "user_list[i] in computer_list[i]:", you're comparing an integer to a list. What you're trying to do is see if the integers are the same.

Do this instead:

```
if user_list[i] in computer_list and user_list[i] == computer_list[i]:
```

Keep working on the rest of it yourself. It's easy to give up when you can't get past an error. Now that your error is resolved, you should be able to get the rest.